# Openerp Custom Field return false value in web service api

Tags: php, odoo

I've just created a custom field for product.product model in Openerp 9 enterprise edition through Settings > Technical > Fields > Create, this creation is success and i can insert a value . But why this custom field value is returning a false while i'm calling in web service api using xmlrpc PHP ? is there a some other thing i should do on a new custom field creation ?

> Here's a chunk of my code in web service api using PHP , the custom field is x_ee_entry_id

$ids = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,'product.product', 'search',  array(array(array('name', 'ilike',  '%'.$product_name.'%'  ))), array('limit'=>100));

$records = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'product.product', 'read', array($ids), array('fields' => array('default_code','display_name','name','lst_price','price_extra','taxes_id',
          'image','id','x_ee_entry_id') ) );`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you verified the particular record has a value for your field using postgresql? Can you provide more information about your custom field? What type of field is it?

Comment: i don't think you need the `%` around the search condition

Comment: @phillipstack i'm using online version of openerp, how can i see the postgresql field value ? Here is  a screenshot of my custom field settings  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2BjaRF7-9laYmdKWUJyVlh4ZFU[/link]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2BjaRF7-9labnNDSXdlM0tXamc[/link]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2BjaRF7-9laWHdLbkVyR0pld2M[/link]

Comment: So just to be clear. In odoo web interface you open up a record and you can see the value you expect. And you run your php shown above (which I agree with danidee you do not need the %). But you are saying your php above returns all other fields for this record as expected however you are ONLY getting an unexpected False for x_ee_entry_id?

Comment: As for postgres. You really should have a postgresql client of some type even psql CLI (my favourite) so you have a way of knowing exactly what is going on in your database. Just lookup postgresql client application for your operating system. If you select the record using postgres and it returns False then you know the problem is the data not your php.

Comment: @phillipstack that's right i'm getting a false value for x_ee_entry_id, forget about the % i will fix it later , can i connect this postgresql client with openerp enterprise edition ? because we are using the online verision of openerp . Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that is an interesting question. I do not know if you can access your server via postgres. You will have to contact your host.

Comment: Do you know any other settings related to custom field creation in openerp ?

Comment: No other settings. I created a custom field just like you earlier today and found no issues. So either your host is doing something wierd or the data is not in the database. Other than that identify a record in the web interface that you are sure is not False. Get the record id (usually you can see it in your url unless your host's web server is manipulating the url) and in your php explicitly run your read command on this exact record for which you know has a value other than False.